# I want to send a mail using VBScript and CDO

Tags: vbscript

Hi This code is working fine from out side of my OFFICE.But not working in office network...Is port is blocked is the reason??????

The Code is here. Error is also mentioned in the last.

```
MsgBox("Hello world")
Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1 'Send message using the local SMTP service pickup directory.
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).

Const cdoAnonymous = 0 'Do not authenticate
Const cdoBasic = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.Subject = "Example CDO Message"
objMessage.From = """xyz"" <mymail@gmail.com>"
objMessage.To = "anothersmail@gmail.com"
objMessage.TextBody = "hi it's me...." & vbCRLF & "this is wrking so we hav solved the issue."

'==This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing ) = 2

'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver ) = "smtp.gmail.com"

'Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate ) = cdoBasic

'Your UserID on the SMTP server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername ) = "mymail@gmail.com"

'Your password on the SMTP server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword ) = "****************"

'Server port (typically 25)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport ) = 465

'Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl ) = True

'Connection Timeout in seconds (the maximum time CDO will try to establish a connection to the SMTP server)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout ) = 60

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

'==End remote SMTP server configuration section==

objMessage.Send
MsgBox("Hello world")
```

---

Error:line 52,Char 1,Error the transport failed to connect to the server. code:80040213..

Answer (score 1):

http://www.paulsadowski.com/WSH/cdo.htm

http://forums.aspfree.com/asp-development-5/cdo-message-1-error-80040220t-47913.html

here u can find many examples

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using GMAIL addresses, I'm guessing that you're not running an email server on the same machine as where you're running this script?

If so, you'll have to configure it to connect to the remote server. This article describes how to do that:  [VBScript To Send Email Using CDO](http://www.paulsadowski.com/WSH/cdo.htm)

Look at the section called *Sending a text email using authentication against a remote SMTP server.*

I think that the server is *smtp.googlemail.com* and the port is *587*.

Comment: Hi,As you told is perfectly fine,and the link which you provide is very good.Only that link is enough for my reqirement.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SMTP server of gmail then first try to telnet the smtp server og gmail on port 25. If it says blocked try port 465. either should work. whichever port is open use that on yoru script. If none works you gotta discuss with your network admin. firewall rules is preventing you to communicate over the office LAN.